# Get Javascript variable in HTML Body

Tags: javascript, html, xml

I wrote a code that take's the image path from an XML file using Javascript, and store's it in a Javascript variable :

```
var str2 = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("picture")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue;
```

so now in my body section i need to create an image tag    `img src= ??????`

I want the src to be the value of my javascript variable, how to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> so now in my body section i need to **create an image** tag img src=
>   ??????

You can do this:

```
var str2 = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("picture")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue;
var img = document.createElement('img');
img.src = str2;
document.body.appendChild(img);
```

Comment: +1 @sarfraz You have a small typo 'documnet' should be spelled 'document'. Sorry, I don't have edit permissions.

Answer (score 3):

Do this:

```
var img = document.createElement( "IMG" );
img.src = str2;
document.body.appendChild( img );
```

Make sure you do this in the onload even (otherwise the `document.body` element might not be ready to accepts new childs yet).